# Flink application writing to S3a filesystem failed due to AWS credential not found from any loader

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I trying to do migration from S3n to S3a for my Flink application.
I have written my custom rolling sink for writing data into aws S3. Its accepts URL as base path like S3a:///.
Its works for S3n and when i did following changes for S3a, its throws following exception.
Its seems like core-site.xml is not picking up incase of S3a for AWS credential.
its using AWS default loader for loading the credentials.
Please let me know what configuration is missing for this. Right now i am running in eclipse development enviornment,how its works in flink cluster mode?

Exception is:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
                at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3521)
                at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1031)
                at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:994)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:297)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2316)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:90)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2350)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2332)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:369)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
                at com.abc.abc.common.sinks.CustomRollingSink.open(CustomRollingSink.java:260)
```

I am using the flink 1.0.0 version and following dependecies into the project pom file and core-site .xml for AWS credentials.

```
<property>
<name>fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId</name>  
<value>value..</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
<value>values...</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>        
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>
```

Pom file:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key`?

Comment: Thanks for input. after these changes not got the same exception... I am getting another exception which i have resolved through setting the propertie  <name>fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled</name>. Flink documentation https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/setup/aws.html should be updated for S3a connection.

Comment: @PankajSaxena were you able to get Flink to write to S3, I have the exact same configuration, with maxim's changes, and I still get the same error.

Comment: @64K Its works with me with following property set in core-site.xml <property>
  <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
  <description>The implementation class of the S3A Filesystem</description>
</property>

Comment: @64K you can refer this link for setting the s3 property https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

Comment: Thanks, it was the location of the core-site.xml that resolved my issue